# How do I set favicon in vue project?

Tags: vue.js

I've been tasked to add a favicon for a vue/firebase project. After googling and looking through various stackoverflow posts, everyone seems to be referering to webpack projects which this is not.

My project structure looks as following and the favicon is located in the /assets folder
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYUEO.png). I'm completely lost as to where I'm supposed to add the favicon since With Vue-CLI 3 and 4 (and up) no index.html is created in the src folder. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Surely you need to have an index.html somewhere

Comment: Outside `src` folder you will have `index.html` under `public` folder you have to set `favicon` there.